# How to produce this menu effect in flutter?<image attached>

Tags: flutter, user-interface

[This effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAhZ7.png)

I couldn't find any ways to produce this type of home screen card slide menu effect or any combination of widgets to reproduce this, sure could use some help.

Comment: use pageview builder with pagecontroller to achive this kind of effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type of custom Drawer done with `Stack`, `AnimatedBuilder` and `Transform`. Most difficult part there is gesture behavior, that could be copied from original Drawer flutter source code.

Marcin Szałek represented this implementation, alongside with few other features on Flutter Europe.

At [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FCyoHclCqc8) video he describes how he done it.

And [this](https://github.com/MarcinusX/drawer_challenge/blob/master/lib/custom_drawer.dart) is link to his github with this feature code implemented.

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated.